# How to connect 2 different PCs at two different physical locations through gRPC without using Cloud services

Tags: networking, grpc, communication, http2

I want to connect client PC to another PC through gRPC. I tried this on same wifi network it worked.
But when I connect the client and another PC on different network it gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = stub.SquareRoot(number)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in _call_
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1622034767.452000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":5420,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1622034767.452000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Client.py

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('192.168.0.40:50051')
stub = calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorStub(channel)
number = calculator_pb2.Number(value=16)
response = stub.SquareRoot(number)
```

Server.py

```
print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue with gRPC.
Your server is listening on address `[::]` which is an IPv6 any address, while your client is connecting to `192.168.0.40` which is an IPv4 address.

Comment: @EaswarSwaminathan Thank you for your input. I tried connecting Client using IPv6 but still I am getting the same error.